# How to query all the row that have different value for a same column

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table opinions_answers with several columns, three of them interest me in this case `opinion_id` `date_answer` and `id_politician`.

And I need to query all the row that have a specific opinion_id for which date_answer != "" and where `id_politician` is always different.

I have this:

```
$this->db->from("opinions_answers");
$this->db->where("opinion_id", 1);
$this->db->where("date_answer !=", "");
return $this->db->count_all_results();
```

It works but I don't know how to specify that the column `id_politician` must contain a different value in each row...

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
$this->db->from("opinions_answers");
$this->db->where("opinion_id", 1);
$this->db->where("date_answer !=", "");
$this->db->group_by('id_politician');
return $this->db->count_all_results();
```